# JDB ignores breakpoint for method in Scala object

Tags: scala, breakpoints, jdb

I am using JDB to debug Scala code, and it mostly works so far. However, one particular breakpoint is never hit, and it is set on a method of a Scala object (on method entry, not on a particular line number).

As I step through the code I can see that method being entered, but the breakpoint is never ever hit, no matter how many times I try. Every other breakpoint I have set, including breakpoints on code in the same project, is hit.

```
$ jdb -version
This is jdb version 1.6 (Java SE version 1.6.0_23)
```

I have set the breakpoint both with and without the $-suffixed class name.

What could be the problem here?

There is no other method with the same name on that class, so even though I haven't told JDB the method argument types, that shouldn't matter - there's no overloading going on here.

Comment: Can you post your code? I got `gdb` to stop both inside `Main.main` and inside `Main$.main`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce this after restarting jdb.

In any case, I was accidentally using jdb from a different JDK (OpenJDK).